# How to access sub-objects of Yii relational query

Tags: php, yii, cactivedataprovider

A table **`Product`** contains has_many relationship with a table `**Slab**` that further contains has_many relationship with a table **`Rate`**.

A relational query is wrapped inside **`CActiveDataProvider`** that joins three tables across certain parameters and return products in descending order of their respective rates.

I want to show the results in tabular form through `CGridView`.

Trying to access only certain columns through following syntax:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                'columns'=>array(
                    'name','slabs.id','slabs.rates.rate'
                )
            ));
```

Unfortunately I can't access **`slabs.id`** because when I dump `dataProvider` object I see that it is annexed to `Product` object through an Array whose `index[0]` contains the `Slab` object, then under `Slab` object `index[0]` has the `rates.rate` object.

It is probably occurring because of the has_many relationship between tables but my query would always return one `Slab` and one `Rate` object.

**How may I access and show them?**

Comment: check this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/385/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-hasmany-manymany-relations-in-cgridview/

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two possible workarounds.
1. Change or add a relationship so you can access a slab and a rate with a has_one relationship.
2. You can add a column to the gridview with a custom name and value like this:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'name',
    array(
        'name' => 'Slab Id',
        'value' => '$data->slabs[0]->id',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Rate',
        'value' => '$data->slabs[0]->rates[0]->rate',
    )
)
```

Where value is a string representing an expression to be evaluated. $data is the main model, in this case Product.